# Django Hide Posts(objects) in UI per User without affecting main model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin, django-authentication

I have an app that display all newsitems having model like:

```
class NewsItem(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="",unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
    hacker_news_url = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    upvote_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

UI:
[image]

I had already setup the default django authentication to view this page.
The ui has hide button for each post. So the problem is **if the logged in user hides the post, it must be hidden for that user only (even after page refresh) without deleting from NewsItem Model/Table**. How to do that? Help Please!

This is my views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login')
def index(request):
    context={'news_items':NewsItem.objects.all().order_by('posted_on')}
    return render(request, "hello.html", context)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set up some kind of "Proof Of Reading" some where.
One way of doing this, is adding up an M2M between `NewsItem` and `User` model.

As soon as a user click on "Mark As Read", you do something like `NewsItem.users.add(request.user)`, and you can filter your `NewsItem` in your `index` view.

```py
class NewsItem(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="",unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
    hacker_news_url = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    upvote_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    users = models.ManyToManyField('your-user-model', verbose_name="Readers", related_name="reads")
```

After 'makemigrations/migrate', In your views:

```py
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login')$
def index(request):
    news = NewsItem.objects.exclude(users=request.user).order_by('posted_on')
    context={'news_items':news}
    return render(request, "hello.html", context)

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login')
@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def read(request, news_item_pk):
    """
    This is the most basic example.
    If you use AJAX Calls, Do not forget to add your CSFR;
    """
    news = get_object_or_404(NewsItem, pk=news_item_pk)
    news.users.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponse()
```

Finally in your views, you should add your `read` view

Comment: Wow!! You are awesome. This so helped me. Thank you very much.